# I keep getting HTML in the XPath output! How do i just get text?

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I keep getting HTML as well as the text I want in Xpath I am running and can't work out how to stop it as i just want the text.

The Xpath

```
hxs.xpath('//h1[@class="body2"]').extract()
```

The HTML

```
<div class="product-title cf">


            <h1 itemprop="name" class="body2">
                Cornish Ale Dozen - Case of 12
            </h1>


</div>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated thanks

Comment: what is `hxs`? what programming language is this?

Comment: Alright, from your questions history, this seems to Python's Scrapy library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure XPath instruction to get text nodes instead of the parent element would be as follow :

```
//h1[@class="body2"]/text()
```

Particularly, using the above XPath should work as you expected, assuming that the library being used to execute the XPath is Scrapy.

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer!! I thought it would be relatively simple.